# storing map[string]interface{} data in diskv value field (expected []byte) for caching http requests

Tags: go

I'm trying to write my own httpcache; I suspect I'm doing it the wrong way, but this is my approach:

My responses look like this:

```
response := make(map[string]interface{})
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
response["status"] = true
response["token"] = someTokenString
response["data"] = someStructSlice // etc
json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
```

My plan now is to use https://github.com/peterbourgon/diskv where I set key equal to URL Path (+ username/token whenever necessary). And then put the value equal to the response data.

Problem is I'm not sure how I should store this data. dickv expects the data to be type `[]byte`, whereas my response data is type `map[string]interface {}`..

Before I begin to try to figure out how to convert it, I figured I'd ask the experts here if I'm even using the right approach. And if I am, is there a simple way to store `response` in the dickv value (type `[]byte`)?

Comment: Well, you're already encoding to JSON, which is output as a `[]byte`. You could just store that. Plus you get the added benefit of not having to decode/encode on every cache hit, just serve the data straight out of cache. You could also use the built-in [`gob` package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/).

Comment: I guess `response` should be encoded using `encodedJson, err := json.Marshal(response)`? and then `w.Write(encodedJson)`?

Comment: Correct. Then you can write the same payload to your cache.

Comment: @Adrian just tested, it works :).. thanks a lot <3.. I want to close thread and accept your comment as answer

Comment: Reposted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're already encoding to JSON, which is output as a []byte. You could just store that. Plus you get the added benefit of not having to decode/encode on every cache hit, just serve the data straight out of cache:

```
if cached, ok := getFromCache(id); ok {
    response.Write(cached)
    return
}
response["status"] = true
response["token"] = someTokenString
response["data"] = someStructSlice // etc
payload, err := json.Marshall(response)
saveToCache(payload, id)
response.Write(payload)
```

You could also use the built-in [`gob` package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/gob/), which is more efficient but more prone to breaking if the data model changes.